# Create a custom keyboard layout for Ubuntu 20.04 - edit programmer Dvorak for ordered numbers

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, keyboard-layout, dvorak

[Here is an image for Dvorak programmer keyboard with ordered keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POIzx.jpg)

I want to customize Programmer Dvorak to swap the number keys 7,5,3,1,9,0,2,4,6,8 in order.
I was amazed I couldn't find the English Dvorak keyboard layout for programmers with top numbers in order on Github.[It is there on Github for windows](https://github.com/jayliu50/windows-programmer-dvorak)

Community pages to create a new KB layout aren't easy to understand. Is there any keyboard remapper for ubuntu like in windows. Else :

> pls guide through the process to edit [kbddvp-1_2_1-src-linux.tgz (4 KiB)](https://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/#Downloads)